# How to include file in gsutil rsync?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

gsutil rsync has an "exclude" option (-x), but no "include" option.
Is there some way to include a selected file without rsyncing the entire directory?
Excluding all but the desired file will not work because random files will be saved to that directory.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you could store the list of filenames in an array and exclude that array using python's negative lookahead assertion with filenames separated by `|`

> https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/92498/include-top-directory-files-in-a-backup/

I had a similar scenario where a line by line copy of files was working out to be too long. I approached it by creating an array with a list of files by running a

```
gsutil ls gs://<bucket_name>/<file_construct>
```

Followed by creating a single variable by delimiting the array elements with a `|`

```
gsutil -m rsync -c -x "^(?!${REGEX_INV_EXCLUSION_LST}$).*'" "gs://${source}/" "${dest}/"
```

Comment: perfect, just a typo

    `gsutil -m rsync -c -x "^(?!${REGEX_INV_EXCLUSION_LST}$).*'" "gs://${source}/" "${dest}/"`

Comment: unfortunately the link to the fedoraproject is dead so this solution is now more of a hint than a complete answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you know the name of a single file you want to sync you don't even need to perform an `ls` like Balajee suggests. Just specify that base file name in the reverse regex:

```
gsutil rsync -x '(?!^myfile\.txt$)' ./directory-with-desired-file gs://my-bucket
```

Example here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/532#issuecomment-394039557

Answer (score 4):

There's currently no "include" option for gsutil rsync.

Answer (score 1):

A work around is to create a rsync_include_files directory and fill it with symlinks to files.  Then rsync the rsync_include_files directory:

```
$GSUTIL rsync -c -C $SOURCE/rsync_include_files/
$DESTINATION/rsync_include_files/
```

But there is a caveat.
When data is restored from backup, files are where the symlinks were, and the symlinks are lost.
To complete the restoration, the files need to be moved manually and the symlinks remade.

Answer (score 1):

@wolfv - *"Is there some way to include a selected file without rsyncing the entire directory?"*

This will allow to you to exclude all files except the one(s) you explicitly   want:

```
fx=""
while read f; do
    if ! [[ "$f" = "thefileiwanttorsync" ]]; then
        [[ ${fx} = "" ]] || fx+="|" 
        fx+="^${f}\$"
    fi
done < <(ls -1 /directory/path) 

gsutil rsync -x "${fx[@]}" /directory/path  gs://bucket/some/directory/path
```

@wolfv - *"Excluding all but the desired file will not work because random files will be saved to that directory."*

I understand the first sentence, but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was apparently requested in June 2018, but given the existence of a rather complicate workaround, the answer was rather negative:

> we're unlikely to get around to implementing this FR in the near
> future.

If the feature request receives enough support, there is some hope they reconsider their position.